# Is it possible to exclude the object with the latest date?

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I have a Core Data Model with an Entity that has an attribute "creation Date"

What I'd like to do is to create a fetch request that has all objects but not the latest. 
As the content of the Core Data store changes while the user looks at the data (i.e. a UITableView) I can not set a "latest Object" and use this for the NSPredicate.

So is there a way to create a format to exclude the data set with the latest date?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can build your `NSFetchRequest` with the following settings:

1. Sort by date, descending order
2. Set the offset to 1

execute the fetch and it will skip the first record.

You can then load it into a `NSFetchedResultsController` if appropriate.

Comment: The man I hoped to get an answer from :)
That would work if I only sort by date, but the user can change the sorting so this will not work.
I tried something yesterday, but not sure if it will work in the long run … for a few test it worked ok. What I did: I created two FRCs. One that is sorted by date, has a batch limit of 1. And the other one does the Fetch for the view and excludes the object that FRC1 returns. If FRC1 has changes I check in the controller did change delegate if there is a newer object, if so, it fires an notification (FRC1 is where the MOC is) and FRC2 predicate is updated

Comment: Again, I don't know if that will stab me in the back sometimes later … but with the first tests it worked.

Comment: Just got back to this :)  Your solution sounds plausible and I can't see an issue with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are displaying the results in a table view, you can manipulate the `datasource` to omit the last result. (You return count minus one in `numberOfRowsInSection`.) This should work perfectly well with a fetched results controller as well. Don't forget to also modify the delegate methods.

If you just need an array (not recommended), read into a mutable array and remove the first or last object (depending on sort order). When the data changes, just re-fetch and replace the array.

Comment: This is not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: 1. I use NSFetchedResultsController and it's delegate methods to handle data changes and to animate changes in the TableView
2. NSFetchedResultsController handles changes in the data store quite well and I don't have to "listen" to changes
3. Putting everything in an array is wasting memory.

EDIT: Hitted enter to early …

Comment: You can use my suggested first method perfectly well with the `NSFetchedResultsController`. Just modify the delegate callbacks accordingly as well.

Comment: Yes, but then I need always to correct the IndexPath … your solution works, no doubt, but it's not what I'm looking for

Comment: You are a really difficult case. So how about doing a `countForFetchRequest` first and then add a `fetchLimit` to the FRC's request? You pay the penalty of two trips to the store, but maybe that's OK for you.

Comment: I know I will now sound a bit snobbish but I really don't mean it that way:
I work with core data for a very long time (I developed on OS X long before iOS was out). But please, don't take this as a snobbish answer! 

I did the fake numberOfRows a few time but doing that will hit you in the back one day.
I.e.
What I did not mentioned above, as it was not relevant for the question, was that the user can change the sorting. Not only per date but also by title or other. And as soon as the sorting is changed you can no longer use the faked IndexPath

Comment: Marcus' approach is similar to mine. `fetchOffset` eliminates the count query before. Thanks M.

Comment: Yes, but only if result is sorted by date … which is not always the case.